# Trying to create a simple clock (ish) app in java - can't seem to do so

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, timepicker

So... I'm building a little app that stores a time value when the user sets one from the TimePicker buttons. Since the android TimePicker has two values currentHour and currentMinute I figure I need to create two strings (one for the hour one for the minute) then concatonate them into a single string which can be displayed as a time value.

Pretty simple, right?

As of now I've come up with the source below - and I feel like I almost have the TimePicker connected to the string for the time value however I have 3 issues:

```
timePicker cannot be resolved   AddEditCountry.java line 104
minEdit cannot be resolved or is not a field    AddEditCountry.java line 37 
timePicker cannot be resolved   AddEditCountry.java line 103
```

...not to mention the TimePicker buttons don't change the (combined currentHour and currentMinute) string.

^ - The BIG problem

```
AddEditCountry.java


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TimePicker minEt;
     public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
     public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
          minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.minEdit);


          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) ? extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) : 0);
             minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString(),
                          timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString());

              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                    nameEt.getText().toString(),
                    capEt.getText().toString(),
                    timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                    minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),/* Storing as String*/
                    codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
           }
}



DatabaseConnector.java




import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



public class DatabaseConnector {

    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

       public void open() throws SQLException 
       {
          //open database in reading/writing mode
          database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       } 

       public void close() 
       {
          if (database != null)
             database.close();
       }       

       public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time, String min) 
               {
                  ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
                  newCon.put("name", name);
                  newCon.put("cap", cap);
                  newCon.put("time", time);
                  newCon.put("min", min);
                  newCon.put("code", code);
                  newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
                  newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);

                  open();
                  database.insert("country", null, newCon);
                  close();
               }


               public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code, String time, String min) 
               {
                  ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
                  editCon.put("name", name);
                  editCon.put("cap", cap);
                  editCon.put("time", time);
                  editCon.put("min", min);
                  editCon.put("code", code);
                  editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
                  editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);
                  open();
                  database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }


               public Cursor getAllContacts() 
               {
                  return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                     null, null, null, null, "name");
               }

               public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
               {
                  return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
               }

               public void deleteContact(long id) 
               {
                  open(); 
                  database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The method setText(String) is undefined for TimePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592471/the-method-settextstring-is-undefined-for-timepicker)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues in the code.

First, you don't need separate TimePicker widgets for hour and minute. So remove *minEt* from your code as well as from layout file.

Second, *timePicker* variable is not declared in the class. Use *timeEt* instead.

Third, i couldn't find *minEdit* variable in the class and if its declared in the layout then the compiler shouldn't complain. Anyways remove it as you don't need it.

You may want to take a look at a working example of using TimePicker. Check [this](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/remindme/6/) out.

*Sample Activity*:

```
public class TimePickerActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int DIALOG_TIME = 100;
    private TextView timeText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        timeText = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(timeText);
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
        switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_TIME:
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        timeText.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                    }
                };
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Im trying to implement one from this tutorial...

http://www.lukehorvat.com/blog/android-time-picker-example/

but I'm still having trouble

(would you like to see the source I've built combining the code from the tutorial?)

Comment: I have provided a simple example which may help for your scenario. You can of course launch the TimePicker dialog on click of a button.